# Problemas com um objeto do tipo Lista Ligada em Java

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Estou aprendendo pelas apostilas da Caelum estruturas de dados, e começei a ver Listas Liagadas, segui todo o código que ela oferece, passo a passo e entendi a lógica da lista encadeada, mas o que não entendi foi essa linha de código:

```
System.out.println(lista); // lista é um objeto to tipo ListaLigada
```

Que tem como saída o array de strings:

> [Paulo, Rafael]

Não entendi, pois no meu código o output que dá é somente do nome da classe + o hascode do objeto. Alguém me explica o que aconteceu??? Todo o código para evitar a burocracia esta aí:

```
public class Celula {

  private Celula proxima;

  private Object elemento;

  public Celula(Celula proxima, Object elemento) {
    this.proxima = proxima;
    this.elemento = elemento;
  }

  public Celula(Object elemento) {
    this.elemento = elemento;
  }

  public void setProxima(Celula proxima) {
    this.proxima = proxima;
  }

  public Celula getProxima() {
    return proxima;
  }

  public Object getElemento() {
    return elemento;
  }
}
```

A classe ListaLigada:

```
public class ListaLigada {

  private Celula primeira;

  private Celula ultima;

  public void adiciona(Object elemento) {}
  public void adiciona(int posicao, Object elemento) {}
  public Object pega(int posicao) {return null;}
  public void remove(int posicao){}
  public int tamanho() {return 0;}
  public boolean contem(Object o) {return false;}
}
```

O código teste:

```
    public class TesteAdicionaNoFim {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListaLigada lista = new ListaLigada();
        lista.adiciona("Rafael");
        lista.adiciona("Paulo");

        System.out.println(lista);
       }
     }
```

**OBSERVAÇÃO: FIZ O MESMO CÓDIGO, IGUALZINHO. CADA LINHA EXATAMENTE A MESMA COM A DA APOSTILA DA CAELUM**

Answer (score 1):

Não posso garantir que o código foi realmente digitado igualzinho. Se foi e a intenção era fazer o que está na pergunta então a apostila está errada, o que não me surpreende de onde veio ela.

Quando você manda imprimir o objeto é algo assim `ListaLigada@52e922` mesmo que receberá.

Para listar os elementos precisa criar um método que liste-os. Será que não deixaram como exercício para você?

Algumas pessoas gostaram de sobrescrever o `ToString()` para fazer isso, eu acho abuso do recurso.

Note que mesmo que esse problema fosse resolvido o método `adiciona()` não faz nada, então não resolve. Essa classe está incompleta.

A solução correta seria a criação de um iterador (através da interface [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), mas isso é complexo demais para quem está iniciando e duvido que uma apostila tenha a intenção de ensinar qualquer coisa além do básico.

Answer (score 1):

Para se imprimir uma lista em Java têm que percorrer a mesma. Segue um exemplo:

```
for (String nome : lista){
    System.out.println(nome);
}
```

A questão de imprimir a lista estará resolvida. Mas como o amigo disse acima, tem que rever o conteúdo desta apostila.

Comment: Isso está errado, a lista dele é ligada, não é uma lista simples, então não é possível varrer de forma simples, ou teria que ter um método que faça isso ou criar um iterador dentro da classe para que possa ser usada junto com o `for`.

Comment: Assim, ok... Acabei aprendendo mais uma também!  Rsrs Obrigado.